# How to draw a moving ball that leaves a trail after it with glsl?

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, fragment-shader

Since there is no accumulation buffer in opengles, what shroud I do to achieve a trail? If I use frame buffer to simulate it, will it cost too much to make the tail looks smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

There is usually not enough data to create a trail from a single state. Even including the speed will make it look very poor if the ball changes the direction of movement. So some kind of information of the previous object states is quite necessary.

It would be possible to use a separate channel to hold the previous states such as stencil buffer or even the alpha channel on which you could create a decay system. That means you would draw the ball on this channel on every frame but before drawing it you would reduce the whole channel by some value so the "older" parts slowly fade out. This separate ball drawing would need to be something like a radial gradient so you will receive a relatively smooth trail but will be far from perfect and for relatively fast movement some additional post processing will be mandatory unless the result is incidently a desired effect.

A more suitable approach is to contain an object position trace on the CPU. Simply keep pushing current positions on the stack and removing those being too old (for instance keep 20 latest positions). Then use these positions to create a shape representing a ball tail. At this point the chances are limitless. For instance you may design a tail as an image and then create a rectangle-like shape from the positions which produces an awesome tail effect if done properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have just test a method similar to your suggestion.I hold the previous states and draw it in frame buffer with glsl. Then blur it to the screen.But there comes out a problem. What if  the ball move so fast that the tail won't be  connected.In addition it's not suitable to limit the speed.

Comment: How can the tail not be connected? It's your application controlling the vertices of the "tail shape".

Comment: With the first approach they are not connected as you are creating a position snapshot on every frame. With the second approach they should be.